# How do i control triple click highlighting? (HTML)

Tags: html

Here an example text

```
Label: Some-text-here
```

How can i have it so when i triple click the line it tries to highlight only is Some-text-here rather then the full line? I could swear i seen it done before with css i just cant think of a way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<span style="float:left">Label</span><span style="float:left">Some-text-here</span>
```

[JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NFcDX/)

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhat of an extension to AXO's answer, but the perfect CSS rule would be `user-select: contain;`, which will prevent selections from crossing the element boundary. This value, however, is only supported in IE/Edge.

An interesting property though of `user-select: all;` and `user-select: none;` is that `all` will highlight the entire element with a single click, and `all` can be put inside `none`, creating a similar effect to `contain` if you put `user-select: all;` on the desired element within a parent element with `user-select: none;`. This is especially useful if you also have bare text in between the elements which you want to prevent being selected, but note that with this solution, the selection can still expand beyond the parent element, skipping over it, so it's not truly containing the selection.

Example:

```css
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.selectall {
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<p class="unselectable">Some extra text: <span class="selectall">ID-12345_678</span></p>
```

Comment: `user-select: contain` seems to be dead

Answer (score 5):

If you use floats to position the texts next to each other they'll still be considered separate paragraphs and achieve the desired result.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="float:left">Label:</div> 
    <div style="float:left">some text here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some situations it may also be appropriate to exempt some parts of text from selection. The *experimental* [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) style can be used for that purpose, like so:

```css
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class='unselectable'>Label: </span>some text here
```

Comment: Hello from the future. `user-select` is no longer experimental. See [user-select on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most compatible approach that responds to single, double and triple clicks as expected is on the snippet below. See more here: [user-select - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

```html
<span style="user-select: none">Label: </span><span style="user-select: text">Some-text-here</span>
```

Comment: In Chrome, `user-select: text` seems to selects a trailing newline.