# Double-click and copy <span> text without picking up newline

Tags: html, css

I have a two `<span>` texts, side by side, and I would like to be able to double-click on one of them, Ctrl+C copy, and then Ctrl+V paste into a terminal without pasting a newline at the end, which causes the command to be submitted upon pasting.

The code below in Chrome causes the newline character to be picked up, however, this does *not* happen in the following working example: [jsfiddle.net/8h1awgLk](https://jsfiddle.net/8h1awgLk/)

**Q:** How can I ensure that when I try to double-click `/etc/udev/rules.d` and then copy-paste it, a newline will not be pasted at the end?

CSS:

```
.label {
  float:left;
}

.mono {
  font-family: Courier New, Courier, Lucida Sans Typewriter, Lucida Typewriter, monospace;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="label">Path:&nbsp;</span>
<span class="mono">/etc/udev/rules.d</span>
<br />
```

---

I just discovered that in Firefox, double-clicking on `/etc/udev/rules.d` will also select the "Path:" text.  So, I definitely need a better approach here.

Comment: It's strange but newline is happening because of the `<br/>` you got there. If you can get rid of it it's ok. And for the firefox problem, you can apply `display:inline-block;` css rule for your `span`s.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687941/how-do-i-control-triple-click-highlighting-html

Comment: not a duplicate, the linked answer still captures a newline if anything follows the span